# Make cryptsetup available from the Busybox Ash during boot for remote unlocking

Tags: debian, luks, initramfs, busybox

I've tried to set up remote unlocking following online guides like [these](https://hamy.io/post/0009/how-to-install-luks-encrypted-ubuntu-18.04.x-server-and-enable-remote-unlocking/). First I tried it on ubuntu 18.04, I am trying now in Debian buster. In both cases I was able to set up dropbear to give me access, but when problems arose that were difficult to debug, I disabled forcing the `cryptroot-unlock` binary on the ssh session and fall into the Busybox Ash shell.

Once I'm inside the busybox shell via Dropbear, I noticed that the examples all show `cryptsetup` command to be available from the busybox shell, but for me this wasn't the case in both cases `cryptsetup command not found`. So I'm figuring I need to install `cryptsetup` into the initramfs somehow, although I already installed `cryptsetup-initramfs` (version `2:2.1.0-5+deb10u2`) and I'm not sure what else to do here

Answer (score 2):

Use the command `cryptroot-unlock` from the shell, not `cryptsetup`.

Here is an example of a one-line remote login to enter the decrypt password:

```
ssh -ti /path/to/private_key_file -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@machine.requiring.unlock cryptroot-unlock
```